# View binding in traditional way using findViewbyId in LifecyclerObserver

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, findviewbyid, lifecycleowner

I am new to the lifecycle observer (fragment). I am trying to link the views defined in XML with fragment. traditionally, we use to do it in **onActivityCreated** method using **findViewById**. How can we do it while using lifecycle observer?

Kindly do not suggest data binding. I am trying to avoid it in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
class TestFragment : Fragment(), LifecycleObserver {


@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
fun doSomethingOnActivityCreated(){
    requireActivity().lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
    
    //do stuff
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    requireActivity().lifecycle.addObserver(this)
}
```

}

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my question. I was trying to handle the view linkage in the life cycle observer class. for that, I needed the parent view reference. But I achieved it by passing the parameter to the class. the main issue is I am unable to figure out a scenario that can only be handled by lifecycle observer now because of the depreciation of onActivityMethod